# Authorize.net payment gateway on wordpress e-commerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Does the wordpress e-commerce plugin has the authorize.net payment gateway?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the WordPress E-Commerce plugin has an Authorize.Net payment gateway integration module and you do not need gold cart for that if you use the [following WP E-Commerce Authorize.Net module from codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-ecommerce-authorizenet/4494116).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to also install the [gold cart plugin](http://getshopped.org/premium-upgrades/premium-plugin/gold-cart-plugin/) for that.

Comment: Note: [Faria's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16611003/481584) says that the WP E-Commerce Authorize.Net module is enough (saying it myself since Faria cannot comment your post yet)

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins available that support Authorize.net, however, they don't all support the same interfaces. Authorize.net provides the following APIs

SIM = Simple Integration Method
AIM = Advanced Integration Method
ARB = Automated Recurring Billing
CIM = Customer Information Manager

All but the first require that you also install a secure certificate on your site to encrypt communication of credit card or check details. The first option, SIM, sends the user to Authorize.net's site to complete the payment, so it's on their secure connection.

CIM isn't likely to be supported in a plugin since it's for more advanced ecommerce functions and wordpress wouldn't be a fit for them anyway.

There are some free options that you can find in the directory:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=ecommerce

You can also choose a commercial option, such as this:
http://simplecreditcardpayments.com/

Here are details about how to get SSL on your wordpress blog to support Authorize.net
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F8iPxs4naY