# E Commerce Wordpress Plugin with Authorized.Net Payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce, authorize.net

Can anyone suggest me a proper Free Wordpress E Commerce Plugin with Authorized.Net. I have tried to use [The Cardpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/thecartpress/) where I am finding error on Authorized.Net after payment. And also I have tried [WP E-Commerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/), where I found I needed to install another plugin Gold Cart which is not free. I need your help.

Some other reference are shown below which I used but got errors

[Woocommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)

[Ready Ecommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ready-ecommerce/)

P.S. I saw a reference on Stack Overflow which is not helpful for me

[Authorize.net payment gateway on wordpress e-commerce plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136003/authorize-net-payment-gateway-on-wordpress-e-commerce-plugin)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're limited to free options, which may limit you somewhat as to the quality.

I have a high quality Authorize.net plugin that may fit your needs, but it isn't free:
http://www.danielwatrous.com/authorizenet-for-wordpress

You may also find that you get some support for WP e-Commerce on the wordpress forums. Often the plugin developer has provided an answer already or will reply to a forum post referencing his software.

Use this link to post specifically to his plugin support forum:
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-e-commerce

Comment: I need a free plugin actually.